# xcode's undo is messed up, anyone?

Tags: xcode

I have no explanation for this but xcode sometimes goes nuts for me. 
Sometimes I just copy/paste some code into my code and xcode's undo simply forgets(!) some of the steps so that it ends up with bad code after some undos!

Anyone seen that? Looked up in the web and there is no sign for it!

using the latest xcode (4.5.2) version btw

Comment: I've seen this in 4.3 I think, but not since then.  Anyway this is not a question that can be answered here, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: Thanks, that would help us all alot

Comment: Well what sort of answer do you expect to get?  If there is genuinely an issue with undo in Xcode 4.5.2 all you can do is revert to an older version, or move to Xcode 4.6 (when it's released).  It cannot be "solved".

Comment: in fact this issue has been around for a few versions now. I just thought someone might have some light to shed on this